# Changing the UI from CLI to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visibility

I am using c# wpf application and my main window contains a grid dividing my page into two columns. The first column contains buttons inside of a StackPanel and in it lies my problem:

My code should give different buttons per user entering the program.
I have tried to change the visibility of the not needed buttons to hide/collapse.

The problem I face is that I would like my buttons to rearrange themselves so that they are one on top of the other (when I change the visibility of a button there is a blank space left where the button was before).

My question is: can I make my buttons arrange themselves automatically when visibility is changed or is it possible to add `if` statements in my xaml code (inside them creating a button)?

Comment: What [Visibility enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx) do you use to hide the buttons?

Comment: Can you please elaberate how binding will help with this project?
(I`ve started reading on it but it is a long and wide subject and i would appreciate it if you can shorten my search)

Comment: I tried both "hidden" & "collapse" none had worked

Comment: @YairLandmann use a custom calculator that will bind the position of your buttons according to the visibility. or just add the buttons programatically in the first place, and based on your needs create different buttons every time.

Comment: This should work fine in WPF... what is your XAML code, and how are the buttons being arranged incorrectly?

Comment: I`m tring to get the idea so i change the visibilty as following:                                                 Dis.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;                                                                     The buttons come diractly from the userControl form in to a stack panel with Horizantcly orientation

Answer (score 3):

Below is a complete sample that allows you to experiment with collapsing the buttons. When selecting first checkbox it will show first button, second checbox - second button and so on. Otherwise they will be collapsed. It should give you a starting point for further investigation.

**Note:** It uses [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) which sets visibility to `Collapsed` when `false` and to `Visible` when `true`.

It's complete working sample. Just copy paste it to a new window in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="1" Height="40" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=visChk1,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"/>
            <Button Content="2" Height="40" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=visChk2,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"/>
            <Button Content="3" Height="40" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=visChk3,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"/>
            <Button Content="4" Height="40" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=visChk4,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <CheckBox x:Name="visChk1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="visChk2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="visChk3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="visChk4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It is a very helpful example to understand the concept thanks, but can i use binding to a Enum parameter so let`s say the ADMIN will be able to acsses all function and an "USER" can acsses just one function?

Comment: In the sample visibility is bound to `false` and to `true`. If you want to bind it to something else you have to create your own converter. Otherwise WPF engine doesn't know how to interpret the relation between your custom enum and visibility enum.

Comment: Where can i write the boolean function lets say i want to use binding to a text block and show the button 1 and 3 if the numbet enterd is odd, and 2 and 4 if its even?   Thanks again!!!!

Comment: There is so many ways to skin this cat. Decision depends on your context, complexity you want to involve, technology, design, etc. Some options available (and the list is not exhaustive): method in your code behind that do that; converter; binding to some property in your view model (if you are doing mvvm); rearranging buttons on load depending on the credentials of the user. But the call is yours. Investigate options and apply accordingly depending on your scenario. After all in software development analyzing requirements and making decisions is what you really do.